# grunt-concurrent and handling SIGINT

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, gruntjs, grunt-concurrent

I'm struggling to understand behavior I'm seeing when using grunt-concurrent and trying to handle SIGINT, and hope someone can shed some light on it. Basically: when I use a SIGINT handler within my `function(grunt) { }` declaration, why does only **one** of the concurrent tasks see SIGINT?

The brief setup: I'm using grunt-concurrent to fire off watch and nodemon tasks; the exact concurrent stanza of my `Gruntfile.js` file is:

```
concurrent: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        },
        tasks: [ 'watch', 'nodemon:dev' ]
    }
}
```

I wanted to watch for SIGINT, so that when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I can clean up a few files that get copied as part of the watch task. I began by adding the following to the end of my `Gruntfile.js`, outside of the `module.exports = function(grunt) { ... }` function declaration:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('Cleaning up after the dev server...');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(process.argv));
});
```

When it's included there and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it runs three times — once for the main grunt task I ran (`dev`), and one for each of the two tasks that grunt-concurrent ran (`watch` and `nodemon:dev`). That's clearly not what I intended.

When I move the SIGINT handler within the `function(grunt) { }` method, then when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it only runs once — for the `nodemon:dev` task. What I can't understand is why I'm **not** seeing it run for the `watch` task too (and for the master concurrent task `dev` that fires both of them off!), and it's sorta killing me... mostly because I don't want to depend on this behavior when I can't understand it and can't be sure it won't be the same on all the different machines this app will end up on.

So... thoughts? What am I missing here? Thanks!